# Xamarin iOS native library binding - enum in method call

Tags: xamarin, enums, xamarin.ios

I am binding to a native Objective-C library with a Xamarin binding project.

I can't get method calls that take enums as parameters to work.

In ObjC I have an enum:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MPProviderMode){
/** Unkndown or not available */    
MPProviderModeUnknown  = 0, ...
```

The method I'd like to call is

```
+(MPTransactionProvider * _Nonnull)transactionProviderForMode:(MPProviderMode)mode merchantIdentifier:(NSString * _Nonnull)merchantIdentifier merchantSecretKey:(NSString * _Nonnull)merchantSecretKey;
```

When I try to bind it like this in Xamarin:

Enum:

```
[Native]
public enum MPProviderMode : long
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Live = 1, ...
```

and the method:

```
    [Static]
    [Export("transactionProviderForMode:merchantIdentifier:merchantSecretKey:")]
    MPTransactionProvider TransactionProviderForMode(MPProviderMode mode, string merchantIdentifier, string merchantSecretKey);
```

The method returns null every time I call it. Did I get the binding wrong?

Comment: The binding (and the passing of params) is likely valid, the runtime would throw an exception otherwise. What behavior would you expect? Does the call work from ObjC? In which cases is the method supposed to return null?